# Getting id from eventReceive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get the *id* attribute value from my *div* and put in *calendar*. I've tried many ways without success.

I have the following *div* that I created:

```
vv_lista_servico = vv_lista_servico +"<div class='fc-event fc-list draggable' data-event='{\"id\":\""+item.id+"\"}' data-duration='00:30'>"+item.descr+"</div>";
```

When ready, I have the following html:

```
<div class="fc-event fc-list draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-event="{"id":"244"}" data-duration="00:30">Test 1</div>
```

When I dragging the event into fullcalendar my title and duration works and render on calendar, but the id does not work.

How I should create my html to work and get the id?

Thank's

Comment: `data-event="{"id":"244"}"` will become invalid `html`. Try to get it as `data-event="{'id':'244'}"`. But again, I will not assure that this stands a valid attribute and value..

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event data needs to be valid JSON according to [eventReceive](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/eventReceive/) documentation, so double quotes inside the data-event:

```
<div class='fc-event' data-event='{"id": 1, "randomProperty": "foobar", "title": "This is event 1"}'>My Event 1</div>
```

Sample 
https://jsfiddle.net/5wgoodwp/1/ :

```
/* Edited from http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.5.0/demos/external-dragging.html */
```

HTML

```
<div id='wrap'>

  <div id='external-events'>
    <h4>Draggable Events</h4>
    <div class='fc-event' data-event='{"id": 1, "randomProperty": "foobar", "title": "This is event 1"}'>My Event 1</div>
  </div>

  <div id='calendar'></div>

  <div style='clear:both'></div>

</div>
```

JS

```
/* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

  // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
  $(this).draggable({
    zIndex: 999,
    revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
    revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
  });

});


/* initialize the calendar
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  editable: true,
  droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
  drop: function() {
    $(this).remove();
  },
  eventReceive: function(event) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(event, null, 4));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Smcd, but, i discovered my problem yesterday, and, don't know how solve it... I use jquery + ajax to create the events, and I dont have the proper delegation on fullcalendar, so, i believe that eventReceive don't see the element mapped and can't create on calendar properly! I'm trying to delegate the event Receiver to get the new element that I created, but, without sucess until now, if you have any idea let me know! Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - are you wanting  to send the event that was dropped via ajax to your server and then reload the event(s) after it is saved server side?

Comment: Not really, but, I discovered my problem, It was related to packages interfering in the functioning of FullCalendar ... now everything works correctly! Thanks for your help