# Fullcalendar Scheduler - External Drag and Drop doesn't deliver data-event from HTML

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, scheduler

I'm using FullCalendar's Scheduler and want to make an external drag and drop - but everything I tried to get some data from the HTML didn't work.

For example, I want to overwrite the generated ID of the event with my own to match it in PHP with the entity and create a new object, related to it.

I followed every instruction from *drop*, over *eventReceive* and the properties which must be there. In any way it doesn't work via the *data-event='{"id":"XYZ"}'* and the *data-event='1' data-id='XYZ'* in the draggable HTML-Element.

```
<label class="label-primary form-control draggable draggable-event" data-event="{'id':'XYZ'}">XYZ-Title</label>
```

In my JS the event I do get the event object, but in this object I can't find any of the data I've set to HTML-Object. No ID, No Title, No Color - only thing that works is the duration of the event.

```
eventReceive: function(event) { // called when a proper external event is dropped
    console.debug('eventReceive', event);
},
```

So, how can I set these details - and how to get them with the callback to send them (later) via ajax to PHP. This question is not about AJAX-Calls - just about how to get the data.

Could you please help me, getting this information out from the draggable event? Would be great!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you put your code in a plunkr/jsfiddle

Comment: The data-event data needs to be JSON, so data-event='{"id":"XYZ"}' (invert single and double quotes in your code). Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34515318/5360631

Comment: Thanks for your replies - If found a solution, which is just half-way a duplicate to the other questions. But: please note, that it's about the scheduler and it's tutorials, see longer answer.

Comment: Sorry, marked it as exact duplicate which it isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your replies! I double-checked the valid json string for getting it working and looked at the other question (which are half-way dupliactes). First, my JSON was wrong, but it was one of the things I tried out (with the different syntax), before my post was created. Finally I found the problem in a "simple" code which is used in the tutorial, but didn't match my requirements - but I didn't recognize this as my problem, first.

```
// code from tutorial / example
$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    $(this).data('event', { // HERE: overwrites the data object ==>
        title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
        stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
    });

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });
    });

});
```

Finally, it's about the data part, which overwrites the complete object, delivered. I changed the lines into an extend to set the defaults but also get the object from html:

```
// edited code
$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

    // get the complete object data from html
    var eventData = $(this).data('event');

    // extend this object with the settings you want to make
    $.extend(eventData, {
        stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
    });

    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
    $(this).data('event', eventData);

    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
    $(this).draggable({
        zIndex: 999,
        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });
    });

});
```

Thanks a lot for your help, this problem is solved! :)