# using html data attribute in EventReceive Fullcalendar v3

Tags: javascript, html, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Unable to retrieve the html data attribute in EventReceive in fullcalendar v3

Im using vs2017 mvc and I have tried the sample fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5wgoodwp/1/ but this does not work for me.

Only the text seems to get mapped to event.title i.e. event.title=s
html file

```
<div id='external-events'>
   <div class='fc-event' data-event='{"title":"my event","id":8}'>s</div>
```

calendar

```
drop: function () {
    $(this).remove();
},

eventReceive: function (event) {
    console.log(event);
```

One of the feeds mentions "packages interfering in the functioning of FullCalendar"([Getting id from eventReceive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503751/getting-id-from-eventreceive)). Any ideas will be much appreciated.

im using
header

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/dion.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.1/fullcalendar.min.css' />
```

body

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src=' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.1/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src="~/js/dion.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

output from chrome

```
{_id: "_fc3", source: e, className: Array(0), allDay: true, title: "s", …} 
allDay: true
```

className: [] end: null
source: e {calendar: t, className: Array(0), uid: "2"}
start: Moment
_ambigTime: true
_ambigZone: true
_d: Tue Sep 03 2019 10:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time) {}
_fullCalendar: true
_i: 1567468800000
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_isValid: true
_locale: Locale {_fullCalendar_weekCalc: "local"}
_offset: 0
_pf: {empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
**proto**: Object
title: "s"
_id: "_fc3"
**proto**: Object

Comment: Demo using your exact code and exact versions of the libraries you mentioned. It works perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/4mb9gwv6/1/ (the JSFiddle you linked to in the question is using fullCalendar 2.4, so not a good comparison). Anyway, it's a bit difficult to know what is wrong in your case. Do you have any other libraries / packages present in your page?

Comment: thanks for your help, Ive amended the above to include all the libraries but i see see the same result i.e. no data attributes

Comment: Well the main difference between your version and mine is the dion.js file. What is contained in there? If you remove it, does the problem stop?

Comment: thanks for your help ADyson, I had another js script which seems to have modified the event title which stuffed it all up.